# rounding button

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

How to round button (pushButton) in qt. It is only necessary rounding and nothing more.

Comment: There's no way to make a standard QPushButton "rounder" without doing the painting yourself (either by adapting a QStyle or custom painting in a QAbstractButton subclass).

Comment: no. I did so : ui-> pushButton-> setStyleSheet ("background-color:;" "border-radius: 15px;"); so is rounded. but I need without  "background-color:";

Comment: Ah, forgot about stylesheets :) What happens if you omit the background-color?

Comment: button will be invisible. will be show only her name